# Slider Revolution conflicting with.autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement an autocomplete with JQuery but it is conflicting with Slider Revolution (revslider). I have it working as follows with noConflict but this slows the script down. If anyone can help re-write the script to get around the conflict would be appreciated.

```
var jQuery132 = $.noConflict(true);
(function($) {
    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "<?php
        echo home_url( '/' ).'intellisearch.php';
        ?>",
        minLength: 1
    });             

})(jQuery132);
```

Script being used without noconflict:

```
$(function() {
        //autocomplete
        $(".auto").autocomplete({
            source: "<?php
            echo home_url( '/' ).'intellisearch.php';
            ?>",
            minLength: 1
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "conflicts"? Be more specific.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how noConflict slows the script down.

Comment: I believe the script was performing faster on pages not using revslider prior to the modifications. I am receiving the following error with FireBug: TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: As far as I know, noConflict only returns a reference to the library that has already loaded and doesn't overwrite the $ global. No performance changes there. Have you tried `jQuery.noConflict` ? Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: After looking again I believe you are rightt about NoConflict. I have it a working example in the OP. Many thanks.

Comment: @Cozmoz that is not a working example. There would be more code and I suspect it would also include the slider code that is the root of your issue, based on your description.